# How can I calculate the point to scroll to given a point inside the scrollview's image?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I get a point at an image inside the nsScrollView. It could be anywhere inside the image. I want to calculate the new point to scroll to ? How can I do that?

The iamage is inside an imageview inside the scrollview.

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:2.0];
    NSClipView* clipView = [self.scrollView contentView];
    NSPoint newOrigin = [clipView bounds].origin;

     newOrigin.x = ?
    newOrigin.y = ?

    [[clipView animator] setBoundsOrigin:newOrigin];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Comment: Can't you use something like `convertPoint:fromView:`?

Comment: I am new to cocoa.How would I use that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint event_location = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    _mousepos = [self convertPoint:event_location fromView:nil];
    ...
}
```

Its actually taken from the documentation.